# I left my window open overnight and water got on my Alienware M15 R6. Now the usb ports quit working

Tags: usb, laptop, windows-11, water-damage

I opened the laptop and I didn't see any water inside but whenever I connect a usb device into some of the ports it connects for a while, then disconnects. it will do this over and over. if anyone has any advice I will gladly take it.

Comment: How does water get inside of a laptop by just having a window open?

Comment: @Ramhound magic rain that goes up and sideways, as well as down.

Answer (score 1):

You have had a short-circuit that caused damage to the computer.

You need to take the computer to be repaired.
Continuing on trying to use it only risks more damage.